# Retrieve row order from DataGrid 1.0

Tags: .net, datagrid, .net-1.1, legacy-code

I am working a legacy app which is .net 1.1 and I need to retrieve the rows in a datagrid post sort (by clicking on column header). This sounded like an easy task however, the answer seems to elude me. I can retrieve the rows from the dataset just fine but, they are not sorted again when the header is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer was to create a DataView such as

```
Dim dv As DataView = CType(dg.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView
```

Hope this might help someone else later on...